# how to select some record by random between the some records?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, random

I have a table of images with the some column like this: `id, path, name, likeCount`

I want to have a query that select an image by random between those 20 images with the highest `likeCount` .

Do you have any idea?

Comment: the first one, and actually I want to select one of those 20 images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, you need to do that in 2 steps:

First, you need to create a view in which you store the 20 first images with the highest `likeCount`:

```
    CREATE VIEW first_Twenty_images AS
    SELECT *
    FROM images_table
    ORDER BY likeCount DESC
    LIMIT 20
```

After that, you can select a random element from them by using the view we created just before:

```
SELECT * FROM first_Twenty_images ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this Not Tested.

```
Select * from ( select @a:=@a+1 no, id, path, name, likeCount from 
table1,(SELECT @a:= 0) AS a order by  likeCount desc limit 20 ) as tt order by
Floor(RAND() * 20) limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can user rand() in query

```
  SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND()
```